# Bounded holomorphic and bounded biholomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

We call an open subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ a bounded holomorphic domain, if there exists a non-constant bounded holomorphic function $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$ and we call an open subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ a bounded biholomorphic domain, if there exists an injective bounded holomorphic function $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$.

Is every bounded holomorphic domain, bounded biholomrphic?

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment, not an answer. It's possible that the answer is well known:

After a conformal mapping we can regard $U$ as a subset of $\Bbb C_\infty=\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ with $\infty\in U$. So $U=\Bbb C_\infty\setminus K$, where $K\subset\Bbb C$ is compact.

Now by definition if $U$ is a bounded holomorphic domain then $K$ has positive [analytic capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_capacity). There is a canonical bounded analytic function $f$ associated with any set of positive analytic capacity, the "Ahlfors function". That $f$ satisfies an extremal property; maybe that extremal property implies that $f$ is injective? It may well be well-known that the Ahlfors function is injective...

Comment: well we do have a counterexample- http://mathoverflow.net/q/125682/84962

Comment: @Hmm. Huh. You should post an answer or at least a comment to the OP at the top of the thread so I can delete this "answer" without destroying the answer...